# Do i need two ips AND 2 nameservers for cpanel?

Tags: linux, networking, dns, bind

I have two static ip4 addresses and one dedicated linux box just for my DNS (its a debian based server running bind9 and all it will do is manage name servers).

Should I have a second box also running nameserver (bind) software on the second ip, or both ip addresses pointed to the first box?

I want to run cPanel and getting it all set up and planned out is a bigger job than I had though originally.

Answer (score 0):

Cpanel is not yet supported on Debian so first you will have to reinstall the server with either CentOS or RHEL

Once you reinstalled server , ask your server provider for additional IPs and you can use 2 IPs to work as name servers on cpanel.

There is no need of additional server to act as name servers.

Comment: Using CentOS 7 now. Its my own server in my office and it already has two dedicated IP addresses. Just wanted to know if i need a second DNS only machine.

Comment: You need additional IP not a seperate machine